# awesome wm client.opacity and xterm

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I've:

```
   client.connect_signal("focus", function(c)                                                                                                                             
        c.border_color = beautiful.border_focus                                                                                                                            
        c.opacity=1                                                                                                                                                        
    end)                                                                                                                                                                   
    client.connect_signal("unfocus", function(c)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        c.border_color = beautiful.border_normal                                                                                                                           
        c.opacity=0.9                                                                                                                                                      
   end)
```

To my lua.rc, but there is no opacity change neither in xterm or firefox. It's all the time set to 100% ( I've checked with dialog popup and signals were handled ). Do I need to do something more to have opaque clients available?
I'm on Awesome 4.2 with Lua 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a compositing manager like `xcompmgr` or `compton` for `.opacity` to have any effect.

Comment: Thanks, installing one solved my problem. compton worked out of the box.

Comment: After installing `compton` I needed to add `awful.util.spawn("compton")` just below the code mentioned in the question to make it work.